# Mapping items in one list to the items in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have two lists in Python and I'm trying to map the values of one to the other.

List 1 (coordinates):

```
['7,16', '71,84', '72,48', '36,52', '75,36', '52,28', '76,44', '11,69', '56,35',
 '15,21', '32,74', '88,32', '10,74', '61,34', '51,85', '10,75', '55,96',
 '94,12', '34,64', '71,59', '76,75', '25,16', '54,100', '62,1', '60,85',
 '16,32', '14,77', '40,78', '2,60', '71,4', '78,91', '100,98', '42,32', '37,49',
 '49,34', '3,5', '42,77', '39,60', '38,77', '49,40', '40,53', '57,48', '14,99',
 '66,67', '10,9', '97,3', '66,76', '86,68', '10,60', '8,87']
```

List 2 (index):

```
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3,
 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

For the output, I need to have something like:

cluster_1: [x, y], [a,b]...

cluster_2: [c, d], [e, f]...

cluster_3: [g, h], [o, j]...

I tried doing this in a dictionary, but I can only get it to put in the last coordinate in the for loop for each value. It also always outputs keys starting from 0, and I'm looking to label them starting from 1.

```
for i in range(len(patients)):
    # other stuff
    k = 3
    for b in range(k):
        if cluster == (k - b):
            dct['cluster_%s' % b] = patients[i]
```

which outputs:

```
{'cluster_0': '97,3', 'cluster_1': '86,68', 'cluster_2': '8,87'}
```

I've tried using `dct['cluster_%s' % b].append(patients[i])` but I get a key error on cluster_0. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` your indices and coordinates, then loop over them element-wise and populate a dictionary based on the index.

```
clusters = {}
for idx, coord in zip(index, coords):
    if idx in clusters:
        clusters[idx].append(coord.split(','))
    else:
        clusters[idx] = [coord.split(',')]
```

result, where `clusters[i]` refers the the i-th cluster.

```
>>> clusters
{
    3: [['7', '16'], ['72', '48'], ['36', '52'], ['75', '36'], ['52', '28'], ['76', '44'], ['56', '35'], ['15', '21'], ['88', '32'], ['61', '34'], ['94', '12'], ['71', '59'], ['25', '16'], ['62', '1'], ['16', '32'], ['71', '4'], ['42', '32'], ['37', '49'], ['49', '34'], ['3', '5'], ['49', '40'], ['40', '53'], ['57', '48'], ['10', '9'], ['97', '3']],
    2: [['71', '84'], ['32', '74'], ['51', '85'], ['55', '96'], ['34', '64'], ['76', '75'], ['54', '100'], ['60', '85'], ['40', '78'], ['78', '91'], ['100', '98'], ['42', '77'], ['39', '60'], ['38', '77'], ['66', '67'], ['66', '76'], ['86', '68']],
    1: [['11', '69'], ['10', '74'], ['10', '75'], ['14', '77'], ['2', '60'], ['14', '99'], ['10', '60'], ['8', '87']]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) along with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(list)
for id, value in zip(cluster_indices, values):
    clusters[id].append(value.split(","))

print(dict(clusters))  # {3: [['7', '16'], ['72', '48'], ...
```

A `defaultdict` can be converted to a `dict` with `dict(clusters)`. However, this may not be necessary since `defaultdict` basically extends `dict`.

---

Note: If you need `int` values, then you may replace `value.split(",")` with `[int(v) for v in value.split(",")]` or `list(map(int, value.split(",")))`. Casting them already at this point will save you an iteration later.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(list)
for id, value in zip(cluster_indices, values):
    clusters[id].append([int(v) for v in value.split(",")])

print(dict(clusters))  # {3: [[7, 16], [72, 48], ...
```

---

The *group-by* behaviour extracted to a function `groupby` (using a [lambda function](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) to allow any kind of transformation) so it can be reused:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def groupby(indices, values, map_fn):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for id, value in zip(indices, values):
        grouped[id].append(map_fn(id, value))
    return dict(grouped)

clusters = groupby(cluster_indices, values, lambda _, value: value.split(","))

print(clusters)  # {3: [['7', '16'], ['72', '48'], ...
```

---

Here just another way by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = sorted(zip(cluster_indices, values), key=itemgetter(0))
grouped = groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))
clusters = {
    cluster: [value[1].split(",") for value in list(values)] 
    for cluster, values in grouped
}

print(clusters)  # {3: [['7', '16'], ['72', '48'], ...
```

However, I would use the `defaultdict` approach above or [Cory Kramer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69410359/42659) as it is more simple and easier to read (and therefore preferable)!